# Count companies with more than one contact

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

[image: Below link has the image of the columns]

```
Select count (distinct company_id)
from contacts
group by company_id
having count(contact_id) >1) from contact
```

I used this query but output comes with list of rows and their contact with more than 2.

I looking for single digit like 6 as output.

Comment: Is there a unique index on `(company_id, contact_id)` (like there probably should be)? If not, do you count the same contact twice as "2 contacts" or "1 contact"? Can there be `NULL` values? Do they count as "equal"? Please provide data as *text*, not as image. And always disclose your Postgres version.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select count(*) from
(
 select company_id 
 from contacts 
 where company_id is not null
 group by company_id
 having count(distinct contact_id) > 1
) t;
```

If you are sure that all `(company_id, contact_id)` pairs are unique then `count(distinct contact_id)` becomes simply `count(*)`

Comment: Thanks for reply.  there are some company_id with null, and have contact_id on them, I dont want to use NULL

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the fine print! You commented:

> there are some company_id with null, and have contact_id on them, I don't want to use NULL

So we exclude `company_id IS NULL`. Still unclear how to deal with `contact_id IS NULL`. Some options:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM  (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct                    -- count all contacts
       -- count(contact_id) AS ct           -- count not-null contacts
       -- count(DISTINCT contact_id) AS ct  -- count not-null, distinct contacts
   FROM   contacts
   WHERE  company_id IS NOT NULL            -- "I dont want to use NULL"
   GROUP  BY company_id
   ) t
WHERE  ct > 1;
```

A `HAVING` clause in the subquery is equivalent. `WHERE` in the outer query is just simpler syntax.